# I admired the theme to his theft

Tags: phrase-meaning

Hello everyone I am a non-native student of English. To improve my English I love reading books. Now I am reading a book "Second Hand" by Michael Zadoorian about a boy who owns a second hand store and there is a sentence which I absolutely don't understand. The boy has problems with shoplifters, expecially with a man who is trying to steal a Hawaiian shirt. The boy says:

> I was almost tempted to let him get away with it because I admired the
>   theme to his theft.

Here is the problem: I don't understand the meaning of
"admire the theme to". What does this phrase mean?

Here is the larger context for this phrase:

> The store is looking good these days. Too good. I am having more
>   problems with shoplifters. Last week, I caught some accountant-looking
>   cat trying to steal a Hawaiian shirt. I noticed this guy slip it into
>   his jumbo recycled plastic bag after he bought a big tiki spoon and
>   fork. I don't know if it was an impulse thing or some sort of
>   experimental larceny or what, because he didn't really look like the
>   type (for tiki or thievery), but I actually watched him rip me off. I
>   was almost tempted to let him get away with it because **I admired the
>   theme to his theft**

Comment: We'll need more context to do more than guess.  Please quote a few sentences before the "I admired" sentence.

Comment: The store is looking good these days. Too good. I am having more problems with shoplifters. Last week, I caught some accountant-looking cat trying to steal a Hawaiian shirt. I noticed this guy slip it into his jumbo recycled plastic bag after he bought a big tiki spoon and fork. I don't know if it was an impulse thing or some sort of experimental larceny or what, because he didn't really look like the type (for tiki or thievery), but I actually watched him rip me off. I was almost tempted to let him get away with it because I admired the theme to his theft

Comment: Hello Deadrat. Thank you very much foir trying to help me. Here you have the context

Comment: Sophia Loren with a tiki spoon and fork. :)   https://www.google.com/search?q=tiki+spoon+images&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&imgil=5YFdZt_ueuwc5M%253A%253BH6

Comment: Hawaiian shirt, tiki....  notice any thematic similarities in the items that interested the shoplifter?

Answer (score 4):

"Tiki" is the name for wooden carvings representing mythological figures of the peoples of eastern Polynesia, including the islands of Hawaii.  So the thief bought some wooden utensils with a (presumably) Hawaiian motif, and then he tried to steal a Hawaiian shirt.  (A Hawaiian or Aloha shirt is a short-sleeved, straight-hemmed, brightly-colored shirt printed with flowers, birds, or other Polynesian images).  A "theme" is a readily-identifiable characteristic.

So the narrator is saying ironically that the thief had a theme (things Hawaiian) for his acquisitions and that he was using thievery for that purpose.

"Theme to" means "theme of" here, and it's a common locution, for example, when we're talking the characteristic melody of a composition, as in "the theme to Beethoven's Fifth Symphony."